# pymc3's NUTS can't perform well with my hierarchical model for Bayesian Neural Nets?

Tags: neural-network, bayesian, hierarchical, mcmc, pymc3

I have a Hierarchical model for learning Bayesian networks with only single hidden layer . Network parameters are divided to 4 groups of input-to-hidden and hidden-to-output weights and biases. A Gaussian prior is defined over each parameter group. Hyper parameters,the standard deviations of these priors, have Gamma distributions with parameters alpha=1. and beta= 1/60. output noise is a Gaussian as well; with a Gamma(alpha=1., beta=200 ) over its standard deviation. NUTS step function is used for sampling where its scaling parameter is set to Maximum a posteriori of only the parameters (excluding the hyper-params). data is one dimensional and from [0,1] where A simple one dimensional sinusoid function is used provide the observations. 
I expected the set of sampled networks to interpolate the data and start to disagree/diverge when the distance increases from these observed points, creating shapes similar to the ones produced by Gaussian process models.
 Surprisingly, the results were different from what I had expected. It looks like some annoying constraints prevent the sampler from doing well and sampling from the whole posterior:
[image]
(the red line is produced by MAP network, black line is the underlying function and 3 smal red dots are the data)
pymc3 guys do yo have any explanation about the reason to this problem and how can I fix it?

```
import numpy as np
import  theano
import theano.tensor as T
import pymc3 as pm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy

#
co = 3 #  4 ,5,6,7 ,8
numHiddenUnits = 100
numObservations= 3  # 6 ,7, 8
randomSeed = 1235
numSamples = 5500



def z_score(x,mean=None,std=None):
    if mean is None or std is None:
        mean,std = np.mean(x,axis=0),np.std(x,axis=0)
    return x - mean/std,mean,std



def sample(nHiddenUnts,X,Y):
    '''
     samples a set of ANNs from the posterior
   '''
    nFeatures = X.shape[1]
    with pm.Model() as model:

        #Gamma Hyperpriors

        alpha,beta = 1.,1./60.
        # standard deviation: Bias(Hidden-out)
        bhoSd =  pm.Gamma('bhoSd',alpha=alpha,beta=beta)
        #standard deviation: Weights (Hidden-out)
        whoSd =  pm.Gamma('whoSd',alpha=alpha,beta=beta)
        bihSd =  pm.Gamma('bihSd',alpha=alpha,beta=beta)
        #standard deviation: Bias (input-hidden)
        wihSd =  pm.Gamma('wihSd',alpha=alpha,beta=beta)
        #standard deviation:  output noise
        noiseSd = pm.Gamma('noiseSd',alpha=alpha,beta=200.)

        wihSd.tag.test_value= bihSd.tag.test_value=   whoSd.tag.test_value= bhoSd.tag.test_value = 200
    noiseSd.tag.test_value = 0.002


        #priors
        #Bias (HiddenOut)
        bho = pm.Normal('bho',mu=0,sd=bhoSd)
        bho.tag.test_value = 1
        who = pm.Normal('who',mu=0,sd=whoSd,shape=(nHiddenUnts,1) )
        who.tag.test_value =  np.random.normal(size=nHiddenUnts,loc=0,scale=1).reshape(nHiddenUnts,1)  #np.ones(shape=(nHiddenUnts,1))
        #Bias input-hidden
        bih = pm.Normal('bih',mu=0,sd=bihSd ,shape=nHiddenUnts)
        bih.tag.test_value =np.random.normal(size=nHiddenUnts,loc=0,scale=1)#np.ones(shape=nHiddenUnts)
    wih= pm.Normal('wih',mu=0,sd=wihSd ,shape= (nFeatures,nHiddenUnts))
        wih.tag.test_value =np.random.normal(size=nFeatures*nHiddenUnts,loc=0,scale=1).reshape(nFeatures,nHiddenUnts)#np.ones(shape= (nFeatures,nHiddenUnts))


        netOut=T.dot( T.nnet.sigmoid( T.dot( X , wih ) + bih ) , who ) + bho


        #likelihood
        likelihood = pm.Normal('likelihood',mu=netOut,sd=noiseSd,observed= Y)

        print("model built")
        #==================================================================

        start1 = pm.find_MAP(fmin=scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b, vars=[bho,who,bih,wih],model=model)
        #start2 = pm.find_MAP(start=start1,    fmin=scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b, vars=[noiseSd,wihSd,bihSd ,whoSd,bhoSd],model=model)
        step = pm.NUTS(scaling=start1)
        #step =  pm.HamiltonianMC(scaling=start1,path_length=5.,step_scale=.05,)
        trace = pm.sample(10,step,start=start1, progressbar=True,random_seed=1234)[:]
        step1 = pm.NUTS(scaling=trace[-1])
        print '-'
        trace = pm.sample(numSamples,step1,start=trace[-1], progressbar=True,random_seed=1234)[100:]

           #========================================================================
        return trace,start1

#underlying function
def g(x):
    global co
    return np.prod( x+np.sin(co*np.pi*x),axis=1)

np.random.seed(randomSeed)
XX= np.atleast_2d(np.random.uniform(0,1.,size =numObservations)).T
Y = np.atleast_2d(g(XX)).T
X,mean,std = z_score(XX)

trace,map_= sample(numHiddenUnits, X, Y)


 data =np.atleast_2d( np.linspace(0., 1., 100)).T
 theano.config.compute_test_value = 'off'

 d = T.dmatrix()
 w= T.dmatrix()
 b = T.vector()
 bo = T.dscalar()
 wo = T.dmatrix()
 y= T.dot( T.nnet.sigmoid( T.dot(d,w)+b),wo)+bo
 f = theano.function([d,w,b,wo,bo],y)


 data1,mean,std = z_score(data, mean, std)
 print trace['wih'].shape
 for s in trace[::1]:
     plt.plot(data, f(data1,s['wih'],s['bih'],s['who'],s['bho']),c='blue',alpha =0.15)


 plt.plot(data,g(data),'black')

 # prediction of maximum a posteriori network
 plt.plot(data,   f(data1,map_['wih'],map_['bih'],map_['who'],map_['bho']),c='red')
 plt.plot(XX,Y,'r.',markersize=10)

 plt.show()
```

Update:I changed the code in the following way: First, It seems that assigning the test_values of the model parameters is troublesome! but without a value for 'test_value' , find_MAP  won't converge to a correct point so I removed test_value assignments and feed the find_MAP() with a start point (initpoint). Second To make everything simpler I replaced the Gamma hyper-priors with Half_Normals. Step-method is Also replaced with Metropolis.   Know the sample function looks as follows: 
    def sample(nHiddenUnts,X,Y):
        nFeatures = X.shape[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obzap.png)
        with pm.Model() as model:

```
        bhoSd =  pm.HalfNormal('bhoSd',sd=100**2)
        whoSd =  pm.HalfNormal('whoSd',sd=100**2)
        bihSd =  pm.HalfNormal('bihSd',sd=100**2)
        wihSd =  pm.HalfNormal('wihSd',sd=100**2)
        noiseSd = pm.HalfNormal('noiseSd',sd=0.001)



        #priors
        bho = pm.Normal('bho',mu=0,sd=bhoSd)
        who = pm.Normal('who',mu=0,sd=whoSd,shape=(nHiddenUnts,1) )
        bih = pm.Normal('bih',mu=0,sd=bihSd ,shape=nHiddenUnts)
        wih= pm.Normal('wih',mu=0,sd=wihSd ,shape= (nFeatures,nHiddenUnts))


        netOut=T.dot( T.nnet.sigmoid( T.dot( X , wih ) + bih ) , who ) + bho

        #likelihood
        likelihood = pm.Normal('likelihood',mu=netOut,sd=noiseSd,observed= Y)

        #========================================================
        initpoint = {'bho':1,
                   'who':np.random.normal(size=nHiddenUnts,loc=0,scale=1).reshape(nHiddenUnts,1),
                   'bih':np.random.normal(size=nHiddenUnts,loc=0,scale=1),
                   'wih':np.random.normal(size=nFeatures*nHiddenUnts,loc=0,scale=1).reshape(nFeatures,nHiddenUnts),
                   'bhoSd':100,
                   'bihSd':100,
                   'whoSd':100,
                   'wihSd':100,
                   'noiseSd':0.1
                   }

        start1 = pm.find_MAP(start=initpoint,fmin=scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b, vars=[bho,who,bih,wih],model=model)
        step = pm.Metropolis(tune=True,tune_interval=10000)
        trace = pm.sample(numSamples,step,start=start1,progressbar=True,random_seed=1234)[10000::5]
        #========================================================

        return trace,start1
```

the result after drawing 15000 samples is like this :[image]
Only when I increase the standard deviation of Both  NoiseSd hyper-parameter and 'noisSd' in the initpoint (start point for find_MAP) to 0.1 the results change to look like this: [image]
However such a high level of noise is not desirable.

Answer (score 1):

How does the model fare with a standard Metropolis sampler? This should give some indication as to whether the problem is with the algorithm or lies elsewhere. The fact that the MAP and NUTS estimates are comparable would seem to suggest the latter.

Comment: Since Metropolis and NUTS gave similar results, and since they are quite different algorithms implemented separately, I don't think its a bug in the samplers. I'm not familiar enough with your problem to provide insight, but I'd suggest stripping out detail from the model (e.g. fix parameters) until you get something that makes sense to you, and go from there.